# Missing Picklist values in LWC Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, datatable

The whole component works perfect - only picklist field values are missing. Additionaly after clicking on a pen - the field is moved down. The values are not visible. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

[image]

```
    import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getWoliList from '@salesforce/apex/woliDataController.getWoliList';
import WORK_ORDER_LINE_ITEM_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/WorkOrderLineItem';
import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/WorkOrderLineItem.Status';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
 

//columns in datatable:

const columns = [
    {
        label: 'Line Item Number',
        fieldName: 'nameUrl',
        type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'LineItemNumber' }, 
        target: '_blank'},
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status', type: 'picklistColumn', editable: false, typeAttributes: {
            placeholder: 'Choose Status', options: { fieldName: 'pickListOptions' }, 
            value: { fieldName: 'Status' }, // default value for picklist,
            context: { fieldName: 'Id' } // binding woli Id with context variable to be returned back
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Device',
        fieldName: 'assetUrl',
        type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Device_Name__c' }, 
        target: '_blank'},
        sortable: true
    },
    { label: 'Serial No.', fieldName: 'Serial_No__c'},
    {
        label: 'Product',
        fieldName: 'prodUrl',
        type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Product_Name__c' }, 
        target: '_blank'},
        sortable: true
    },

    { label: 'Quantity', fieldName: 'Quantity', editable:true},

    { label: 'List Price', fieldName: 'ListPrice', type: 'currency'},

    { label: 'Discount', fieldName: 'Discount', type: 'percent-fixed',
    cellAttributes: {
        alignment: 'left'
    },
    typeAttributes: {
        step: '0.01',
    }
    },

    { label: 'Total Price', fieldName: 'TotalPrice'}


]
 
export default class lWCDatatableWithPicklist extends LightningElement {
  
    columns = columns;
    showSpinner = false;
    @track data = [];
    @track woliData;
    @track draftValues = [];
    lastSavedData = [];
    @track pickListOptions;

    @api recordId;
    @track error;
    //error;


    //get object info
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: WORK_ORDER_LINE_ITEM_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;
 
    //fetch picklist options
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: STATUS_FIELD
    })
 
    wirePickList({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.pickListOptions = data.values;
            
            
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
 
    //here I pass picklist option so that this wire method call after above method
    //get records with specific ID and create hyperlinks
    @wire(getWoliList, { woid: '$recordId' }, { pickList: '$pickListOptions' })
    woliData(result) {
        const { data, error } = result;
        this.Data = result;
        if (result.data) {
            
            this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data));
 
            this.data.forEach(ele => {
                ele.pickListOptions = this.pickListOptions;
            });
            let nameUrl, assetUrl, prodUrl;
            this.data = data.map(row => { 
                nameUrl = `/${row.Id}`;
                assetUrl = `/${row.AssetId}`;
                prodUrl = `/${row.PricebookEntryId}`;
                return {...row , nameUrl , assetUrl , prodUrl} 
            });
            this.error = null;
 
            this.lastSavedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
 
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.data = undefined;
            this.data=[];
            this.error = error;
        }
    };
 
    updateDataValues(updateItem) {
        let copyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
 
        copyData.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
            }
        });
 
        //write changes back to original data
        this.data = [...copyData];
    }
 
    updateDraftValues(updateItem) {
        let draftValueChanged = false;
        let copyDraftValues = [...this.draftValues];
        //store changed value to do operations
        //on save. This will enable inline editing &
        //show standard cancel & save button
        copyDraftValues.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
                draftValueChanged = true;
            }
        });
 
        if (draftValueChanged) {
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues];
        } else {
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues, updateItem];
        }
    }
 
    //listener handler to get the context and data
    //updates datatable
    picklistChanged(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        let dataRecieved = event.detail.data;
        let updatedItem = { Id: dataRecieved.context, Type: dataRecieved.value };
        console.log(updatedItem);
        this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem);
        this.updateDataValues(updatedItem);
    }
 
    //handler to handle cell changes & update values in draft values
    handleCellChange(event) {
        this.updateDraftValues(event.detail.draftValues[0]);
    }
 
    handleSave(event) {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        this.saveDraftValues = this.draftValues;
 
        const recordInputs = this.saveDraftValues.slice().map(draft => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
            return { fields };
        });
 
        // Updateing the records using the UiRecordAPi
        const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
        Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
            this.showToast('Success', 'Records Updated Successfully!', 'success', 'dismissable');
            this.draftValues = [];
            return this.refresh();
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.showToast('Error', 'An Error Occured!!', 'error', 'dismissable');
        }).finally(() => {
            this.draftValues = [];
            this.showSpinner = false;
        });
    }
 
    handleCancel(event) {
        //remove draftValues & revert data changes
        this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lastSavedData));
        this.draftValues = [];
    }
 
    showToast(title, message, variant, mode) {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant,
            mode: mode
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
 
    // This function is used to refresh the table once data updated
    async refresh() {
        await refreshApex(this.woliData);
    }
}
```

Comment: are those missing values assigned to the record type you are using? you can check by going to *Object Manager -> Work Order Line Item -> Record Types* then select the record type you are using and open the status field.

Comment: no @McCubo :( everything is here

Comment: Have you tried adding a `console.log` to this variable: `this.pickListOptions` perhaps they are included in the list but somehow not rendered in the picklist component.

Comment: @McCubo I am doing it from scratch, and it is working finally, but the problem is when I am using the scroll bar the whole field is moving down, the same as on my screenshot - row is up, field for choosing value is down... as on my screenshot